# Truncation error in retrieving average value from H2 with Jooq

Tags: java, database, jooq, truncation

I am trying to retrieve the average value form an H2 database with Jooq.

Here is the line of code:

```java
double dataSize = context.select(avg(PLC_DATA.LOAD_MAX_TOT))
                         .from(PLC_DATA)
                         .where(PLC_DATA.EVENT_INSTANT
                         .greaterThan(fromInstant)
                         .and(PLC_DATA.EVENT_INSTANT.lessThan(toInstant))
                         .and(PLC_DATA.ID.like("%" + id + "%")))
                         .fetchOneInto(Double.class);
```

The line of code works but the result does not have the decimals (i.e. 628.00)

The data in the column `LOAD_MAX_TOT` is integer, do I have to cast the Integers in some way?

---

As suggested by Simon Martinelli, the error is not in jooq but in my SQL Code. To get the result with the decimal part I need to cast the value before applying the average function.
This is the correct SQL statment:

```sql
select avg(cast(PUBLIC.PLC_DATA.LOAD_MAX_TOT as double)) 
   from PUBLIC.PLC_DATA 
   where (PUBLIC.PLC_DATA.EVENT_INSTANT > cast(? as timestamp) and 
          PUBLIC.PLC_DATA.EVENT_INSTANT < cast(? as timestamp) and 
          PUBLIC.PLC_DATA.ID like cast(? as varchar)) 
   {1: TIMESTAMP '2021-03-06 10:23:00', 2: TIMESTAMP '2021-03-06 12:32:00', 3: '%%'}
```

and the corresponding Jooq Java code:

```java
context.select(avg(cast(PLC_DATA.LOAD_MAX_TOT, Double.class))).
       from(PLC_DATA).
       where(PLC_DATA.EVENT_INSTANT.greaterThan(fromInstant).
       and(PLC_DATA.EVENT_INSTANT.lessThan(toInstant)).
       and(PLC_DATA.ID.like("%" + id + "%"))).
       fetchOneInto(Double.class)
```

The result is now:

```
Double@242 "628.5714285714286"
value:628.571429
```

Comment: If you directly execute the SQL query that jOOQ generates do you get the correct result?

Comment: you are right, the SQL statement (select avg(PUBLIC.PLC_DATA.LOAD_MAX_TOT) from PUBLIC.PLC_DATA where (PUBLIC.PLC_DATA.EVENT_INSTANT > cast(? as timestamp) and PUBLIC.PLC_DATA.EVENT_INSTANT < cast(? as timestamp) and PUBLIC.PLC_DATA.ID like cast(? as varchar)) {1: TIMESTAMP '2021-03-06 10:23:00', 2: TIMESTAMP '2021-03-06 12:32:00', 3: '%%'}) it give me a number without decimal !!!

Comment: Great that it works. Please add your code as the answer. Thank you